# angularjs ng-file-upload ERROR: ng-file-upload.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: a.$ngfDimensionPromise.finally is not a functionf.imageDimensions

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am using the GIT below to upload images into my angular application

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

The HTML is as follows:

```
 <body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h4>Upload on file select</h4>
  <button type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)"
          accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="1MB">
      Select File</button>
  <br><br>
  File:
  <div style="font:smaller">{{f.name}} {{errFile.name}} {{errFile.$error}} {{errFile.$errorParam}}
      <span class="progress" ng-show="f.progress >= 0">
          <div style="width:{{f.progress}}%"  
               ng-bind="f.progress + '%'"></div>
      </span>
  </div>     
  {{errorMsg}}
</body>
```

The js scripts are:

```
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadFiles = function(file, errFiles) {
        $scope.f = file;
        $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
        if (file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                data: {file: file}
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * 
                                         evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }   
    }
}]);
```

and CSS as below:

```
.thumb {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}

form .progress {
    line-height: 15px;
}

.progress {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px groove #CCC;
}

.progress div {
    font-size: smaller;
    background: orange;
    width: 0;
}
```

issue is that when I try to run an upload the browser (chrome developer tool) throws the following errors:

> ng-file-upload.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError:
>   a.$ngfDimensionPromise.finally is not a functionf.imageDimensions
>
> @ ng-file-upload.min.js:2m @ ng-file-upload.min.js:2(anonymous
>   function) @ ng-file-upload.min.js:2n @ angular.min.js:6i @
>   ng-file-upload.min.js:2f.validate @
>   ng-file-upload.min.js:2i.updateModel @ ng-file-upload.min.js:2m @
>   ng-file-upload.min.js:2dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2h @
>   jquery.min.js:2$scope.uploadFiles @ contacts.js:200(anonymous
>   function) @ angular.min.js:74m @ ng-file-upload.min.js:2(anonymous
>   function) @ ng-file-upload.min.js:2i @ angular.min.js:79(anonymous
>   function) @ angular.min.js:80$eval @ angular.min.js:92$digest @
>   angular.min.js:90$apply @ angular.min.js:92(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min.js:108e @ angular.min.js:31(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min.js:34
>
> angular.min.js:63 TypeError: f.finally is not a function
>
> ```
> at d.dataUrl (ng-file-upload.min.js:2)
> at ng-file-upload.min.js:2
> at angular.min.js:108
> at e (angular.min.js:31)
> at angular.min.js:34
> ```

Comment: `a.$ngfDimensionPromise.finally is not a functionf.imageDimensions` **<<<**  Fix this problem.

Comment: how ???? any suggestion more than welcome :) !!

Comment: Start by identifying the line of code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks Robert, the error is occurring within the  ng-file-upload.min.js: file,  window.XMLHttpRequest||window.FileAPI&&FileAPI.shouldLoad||(window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype     this is just a small extract of what is highlighted as an error... its a massive js file...

Comment: Ah, the perils of copy/pasting code from the internet without understanding how it works.

Comment: sorry I did not know you understand 100% what that native js library file does :)

Comment: so do you then know why is it complaining about the code within a js library file ? probably I am missing a reference ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now up and running !! :)

It was a deployment issue as I suspected because error was pointing out that a function within the ng-file-upload.min.js was not found !!

> ng-file-upload.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError:
>   a.$ngfDimensionPromise.finally is not a functionf.imageDimensions

I found that "ng-file-upload" was not fully installed under the node-modules folder, after uninstalling and installing it again, I could see that the expected files were indeed found under node-modules/ng-file-upload and error was gone !! :)

Just remember to run the command below within your project folder

npm install ng-file-upload

And then just follow instructions found on this url https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload, it will work !! :)